# Know if a new video is added in youtube api

Tags: react-native, push-notification, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Hi how can I check via Youtube api if a new video is added to a playlist ? I want to implements push notifications on 3 playlists for example and whenever a new video is added to playlist 1, then the user will receive a new video.

Thanks !

Comment: The youtube api doesnt support push notifications your going to have to poll the api for changes.

Comment: Yeah I will manage the notification with an other API, all I want is to know if there is a new video ? Do we have a function that let us know that ?

Comment: No your going to have to cache whats there and make requests to check if theres anything new thats what Polling means.